# Why are my image with text not being displayed in the downloaded PDF file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, jspdf

I am currently downloading PDFs using HTML and the data is being downloaded properly. However, when I add an image with my text, the image is not displayed in the downloaded PDF. I want the image to be visible in the downloaded PDF file, just as it is visible in the UI.

**This issue is fixed**

```
export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const exportToPdf = (name, div) => {
    const input = document.getElementById(div);
    html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
      // Create a new PDF canvas.
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      const pdf = new JsPDF("p", "pt", [canvas.width, canvas.height]);
      // then we get the dimensions from the 'pdf' file itself
      const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
      const width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const height = (imgProps.height * width) / imgProps.width;
      // convert your PDF and save to file
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 0, width, height);
      pdf.save(`${name}.pdf`); // Download the rendered PDF.
    });
  };
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      rowSpacing={4}
      component="div"
      id="exportTofile"
    >
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
          <Box flexGrow={1}>
            <Typography variant="h3"> Dashboard</Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" gap={2}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              title="Download"
              onClick={() => {
                exportToPdf("exportToPdf", "exportTofile");
              }}
            >
              DOWNLOAD
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4">First summery</Typography>
        <Box mt={2}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">
            <Box
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: commentData
              }}
            />
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Second summery</Typography>
        <Box mt={2}>
          <Box>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">
              <Box
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html:
                    "<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>\n"
                }}
              />
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```